# a question about central simple algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question about double centralizer therorem. Thanks for any help.

" If $A$ is a finite-dimensional central simple algebra over a field $F$ and $B$ is a simple subalgebra of $A$, then $C_A(C_A(B)) = B$, and moreover the dimensions satisfy
$\mathrm{dim}_F(B)\cdot\mathrm{dim}_F(\mathrm{C}_A(B))=\mathrm{dim}_F(A)$."

Where is my mistake?

If A is the algebra of all $2\times 2$ matrices, then $A$ is a central simple algebra. Set $B$ the set of all matrix such that all enteries exept $1,1$ is zero. Then $B$ is simple subalgebra. But the equations in the Theorem is not true for this example.

Comment: $B$ is not a subalgebra (in the sense of the theorem) since it misses the unit element of $A$.

Comment: Thanks sebastian. In the theorem $B$ must be an algebra with unit?

Comment: @Sebastian, Do you know Is there any uniform way to find simple subalgebras for the algebra of all  $n\times n$ matrices? (in the sense of theorem)

Comment: First of: Your algebra $B$ does have a unit but for the theorem to apply this would need to be the unit of $A$.    Second: I am not aware of a way to construct "all" (in some sense) simple subalgebras of the matrix ring (there are a few easy ones e.g. the maximal subfields)

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck Consider writing a solution, please.

Comment: Please see my answer below. If you want me to expand on something just leave another comment.

Answer (score 1):

As per the request in the comments here are some thoughts:

Regarding the question: The theorem (which I know under the name "double centralizer theorem") only works for subalgebras in a strict sense i.e. the subalgebra must inherit all of the structure of $A$ (addition, multiplication, zero, unit element and scalar multiplication). In the example the subalgebra did not contain the unit element of $A$.

Considering the question how one might go ahead to find simple subalgebras of the matrix ring $K^{n \times n}=:A$ here are some (by no means exhaustive) thoughts:

Each simple algebra $B$ over $K$ is isomorphic to a matrix ring $B \cong D^{k \times k}$ for some $K$-division algebra $D$ and some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $d:=\mathrm{dim}_K(D)$ (if $D$ is itself central simple $d$ will be a square but we will not assume this). Then there is a monomorphism (of $K$-algebras) $\rho_D:D \hookrightarrow K^{d \times d}$ ($D$ acts on itself via left (or right if you prefer) multiplication) called the regular representation of $D$. Hence by a rather natural extension we get a monomorphism $\rho_B:B=D^{k \times k} \hookrightarrow K^{dk\times dk}$.

If we are searching for simple subalgebras of $A=K^{n \times n}$ one possible strategy is to consider the divisors of $n$, for each such divisor $d$ construct/ classify the $d$-dimensional $K$-division algebras (this task highly depends on $K$, e.g. if $K$ is algebraically closed you won't find many...) and finally for such an algebra $D$ embed the matrix ring $D^{n/d \times n/d}$ into $A$ in the way I described above.

Depending on the field (and on $n$ obviously) this will yield quite a lot of simple subalgebras of $A$ (for example all extension fields of $K$ of degree $n$ are found as a simple subalgebra of $A$ in this way).

That this list is not exhaustive is easily seen if you consider the diagonal embedding $K \hookrightarrow K^{n \times n}, ~x\mapsto x\cdot E_n$. The image is isomorphic to $K$ hence simple and not found by the above construction. In fact this "diagonal embedding" idea can itself be generalized (along similar lines as above) to yield another family of simple subalgebras of $A$.

I hope this helps a bit.

Edit: Regarding the case of finite fields as per the request in the comments:

The double centralizer theorem states (in addition to the dimension formula above) that if $B$ is a isomorphic to a matrix ring over $D$ its centralizer is isomorphic to a matrix ring over $D^{\text{opp}}$ (the opposite algebra). In the case of fields the opposite algebra is again isomorphic to the field itself.

Not let us assume that $B\cong L^{k\times k}$ then we get $C(B)\cong L^{k' \times k'}$ and the dimension formular yields $n^2=k^2k'^2[L:K]^2$ and hence $[L:K]$ divides $n$.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. So if $K$ is finite field, is it true that all simple subalgebras of $M_n(K)$ have the following form: $M_n(\bar{K})$ where $\bar{K}$ is extention of $K$ such that the degree of extention divides $n$?

Comment: It is certainly true, that all simple subalgebras are are matrix rings over extension fields of $K$ and that the degree of such an extension field has to be less or equal to $n$. I will have to think about the divisibility first.

Comment: Please see the edit to my post above. The divisibility condition holds.

Comment: many thanks Sebastian.

Comment: @maryam You might want to consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer.